# How to get WIF and BIP84-address from SEED of 256 bits?

Tags: address, seed, wallet-import-format

How to get WIF and BIP84-address from SEED of 256 bits?
I generate 256 bits. It can be used for generating SEED (24 words): get SHA256, add first byte and cut into words by 11 bits.
How to get WIF and BIP84-address (bc1q...) from this 256 bits?
I search the algorithm for m/84'/0'/0'/0/0-address.